# Is it possible to map webmail.example.com to specific port on exmaple.com using DNS records

Tags: dns

I have a server running on example.com with certificates and the works.
On this is installed a mailserver and I want the webmail access to be on a different port (like 444 instead of 443).

Is it possible to get this done with an SRV DNS record?

How else?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `SRV` records are used for this kind of needs... but browsers do not take them into account. So there is no solution for your problem at the DNS level.